# Is it possible to set Polymer expressions dynamically?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I want to set filters dynamically. Is it possible?

dynamicFilter is a variable with name of the Polymer expression.

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <span>{{value | dynamicFilter}}</span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no handy way to assign `Filter` to element in runtime. But there is a simple workaround you might find useful:

We are to define the `staticFilter` function, which would be a proxy (wrapper) to calls to `dynamicFilter`s. Assuming dynamic filters to be instances of `PolymerExpression`, this might be put together as follows:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="dynamicFilter">
  <template>
    <span>{{value | staticFilter(dynamicFilter)}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
    PolymerExpressions.prototype.uppercase = function(input) {
      return input.toUpperCase();
    },
    PolymerExpressions.prototype.lowercase = function(input) {
      return input.toLowerCase();
    },

    Polymer({
      value: '¡Hola!',

      dynamicFilter: null,

      staticFilter: function(v, df) {
        return df ? PolymerExpressions.prototype[df](v) : v;
      }

    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
<my-element></my-element>
<my-element dynamicFilter='uppercase'></my-element>
<my-element dynamicFilter='lowercase'></my-element>
```

Now you are free to set the `dynamicFilter` attribute of `my-element` even in runtime.

The reason is that `filters` are compiled and bound during element initialization; for security reasons there is no `eval` behind and therefore you cannot simply pass the arbitrary dynamic value there. On the other hand, filters are ready to receive parameters and that fact actually does the trick. BTW, you might even pass the function instance there whether you are not satisfied with `PolymerExpression`s for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not really clear, but you could use this.injectBoundHTML as a workaround.
When you need to change the filter dynamically, just reinject the content of the span

Comment: This approach won’t work as soon as you need to pass any template-related data to the filter. That said, this filter is intended to be used inside `template repeat` or like.